# VirtualProtect with PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY flag

Tags: c++, winapi, virtual-memory

When I trying to call [`VirtualProtect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on a page of memory to set its protection flags to `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` it fails with the error code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. If I call it with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` or `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` it succeeds.

Is there a reason why it fails with `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY`?

Comment: if you call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` you got more informative status - `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_4` and if you look wrk src code you can easy found your case - [*For private pages, the WRITECOPY attribute is not allowed*](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Mm/protect.c#L726)

Comment: @RbMm: Hmm. Thanks. Is it some kinda protection against loading of modules (DLLs) from memory?

Comment: no, because `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is allowed. really writecopy have no sense on not section cahed by file. for file section this mean - on write allocate page from page file and modify this page instead modify file on disk. but if page initially allocated from page file (not related to file on disk) what sense in writecopy ?

Comment: @RbMm: Well, my assumption was that in case of a write operation onto a write-on-copy page the memory manager will create a writable copy of that page and remap it to the same virtual address.

Comment: and what sense of this ? if page from paged pool (can be swapped on disk) it must be associated with some file on disk or paged file. and if page is modified - it content will be write to disk (file or paged file). if page associated to file and we not want modify content of file - need re-associate this page (but not allocate new memory page) to paged file. but if page already backed by paged file - nothing to re-associate. operation have no sense

Comment: What kind of page do you have, from CreateFileMapping, VirtualAlloc, etc.? Could you pls provide a MCVE.

Comment: @rustyx: VirtualAlloc

Comment: That's interesting. It seems CoW functionality in Windows is limited to [DLL support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/memory-protection) (so file mappings). I wonder how they implement fork() in WSL..

Comment: @rustyx: My guess is that they disallowed setting copy-on-write flag on virtual memory by a user-mode process to give an indication to security software if DLL is loaded from memory. This way if any PE section doesn't have `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` flag set, this means that the module was side-loaded after the process already started, or it was modified afterwards.

Comment: this is not related to any security. the `WRITECOPY` is not valid for **private** pages. simply because no sense have this. we can for example create and map section (can be and in memory only) with `WRITECOPY` protection. but after content of the page modified - protection is changed and we can not return it back to `WRITECOPY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` is only valid for regions that are mapped files and/or section views. If you try to apply that flag on a normal region of memory, like manually allocated virtual memory, or the heap/stack, it will fail.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearly explaining it. Can I ask a follow-up -- if I wanted to map a PE file into memory I'd use `CreateFileMapping` function, right. But if so, it would load it in a linear fashion. In other words, how would I load PE sections at different offsets from the base to preserve that `PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` flag on them?

Comment: Yeah sure. So basically you can use `LoadLibraryA` to load a PE file with the correct protection values set at each section automatically. If you don't want that, you can load it with `CreateFIleMapping` or `LoadLibraryExA` with the flag `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` and then set the protection manually for the regions using `VirtualProtect`.